# button クリック判定

Tags: c#, unity3d

button(バックグラウンド）の上にオブジェクト（imageUI)がある場合、オブジェクトが重なっているところも同様にbuttonの効果があるようにする方法はありますか？

バッググラウンド全体にbuttonがあります。buttonを押すと処理が開始されるのですが、
オブジェクトと重なっている場所は押せないため重なっていても処理ができるようにする
方法はありますでしょうか

Answer (score 3):

やりたいことを「画面全域のクリックを検出したい」だと仮定して回答します。

そもそもUIButtonは使わずにクリックを検出すればよいです。

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");
    }
}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/jp/current/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html

---

もう少し正確に質問しないと回答つきませんよ。

- buttonとは何ですか？
- imageUIとは何ですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました